# Swagger: Sending `Date` as an request header parameter in REST API

Tags: rest, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I need to send **Date** as part request header parameters to my REST API. I created Swagger-UI API document. If I tried accessing my API from Swagger-UI, the **Date** parameter is not getting delivered in application.

If we change the name **Date** to **Date1**, It works fine.

1) Is there any restrictions in sending **Date** as a request-header-parameter?

2) Is there any solution to send the **Date** as a request-header-parameter?

Note: I use chrome browser to test my application through swagger UI.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your Swagger spec, the sample date values you use and your backend code that processes the date parameter?

Comment: The Header parameters I pass:
     Date:Tue, 28 Feb 2016 09:56:57 UTC
     Accept:application/xml
     Http-Version:HTTP/1.1
     Content-Type:application/xml

Back-end code:
@ApiImplicitParam
 (
 name = "Date",
 value = "Request Date (Mandatory)",
 paramType = "header",
 dataType = "string",
 required = true
 )

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, it was removed from the spec as it's considered insecure.

2) No. `Date` is a server ResponseHeader only.